# Entries of the power of a positive real matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Given an $n\times n$ square matrix $A$ such that each $(i,j)$th entry of $A$, denoted by $A_{i,j}$, is a positive real number, what is the expression of the $(i,j)$th entry of $A^k$, the $k$th power of $A$?

\begin{equation}
A^2 = AA, \quad A^3 = AAA, \dots
\end{equation}

I think the result can be given by a very long summation expression, but is there any simplified form? Thanks!

**EDIT:** Use only $A_{ij}, n$ and $k$ to derive the final expression.

Comment: Consider $X_{k+1} = A X_k$ with $X_0 = I$, and $y_k = {\mathbb 1}^\top X_k {\mathbb 1}$.

Comment: You may make use of the Jordan form of $A$ if the underlying field is algebraically closed.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks, I'll check it.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is an $n$-by-$n$ matrix with entries over an arbitrary field and $a_{ij}^{(m)}$ denotes the $(i,j)$-entry of $A^m$, with $m \ge 2$, then a straightforward proof by induction reveals that
\begin{equation}
    a_{ij}^{(m)} = \sum_{k_1,\dots,k_{m-1} = 1}^n \left[ \prod_{\ell = 1}^m a_{k_{\ell-1},k_\ell} \right],~k_0 := 1,~k_m :=j.    
\end{equation}